# php - Boolean parameter in address, how pass to method?

Tags: php, laravel-routing

I have this method:

```
public function getAll( $name = false, $json = false ) {

    if ( $name )
        $sections = Sections::all()->pluck( 'name' );
            else
                $sections = Sections::all();


    return ( $json ) ? json_encode( $sections ) : $sections;
}
```

And address for this is: `example.com/api/sections/all/{name}/{json}`
So i have question for this - how to define address for TRUE parameter?
In my opinion `example.com/api/sections/all/true/true` is not good idea because I'm showing parameters types.
What solution do you propose? Or maybe another method construction?

Answer (score 0):

It seems reasonable to have `name` and `json` as `query parameters`, so your URL becomes something like `example.com/api/sections/all?name=1&json=1`